# What skills are required for a Dreadnought?

Tags: eve-online

I am considering buying myself a Dreadnought, the Gallente "Moros".

Besides the obvious Battleship and Capital Ship Skill to sit in it, what do I need or is recommended in skills to make use of the ship?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### A preliminary warning

My first advice would be: **"If you're asking this question, do not buy it."**

I know, it's harsh. But if you are wondering both what skills you need and what your primary role will be, you might be in a corp that do not need Dreadnoughts for now.

Dreadnoughts are a massive investment in skills and resources. (And time, either to skill or gather these resources)

If you want your first combat Capital, **please consider a Carrier**, which is generally much more useful in a corp that mostly flies subcaps.

### Answering your question

There are tons of skills useful when flying capitals. Of course, **being able to fit all T2 support modules** (even if you fit faction or better, the skill bonus will matter) is always a good idea, and as usual, **all these passive bonuses from all the generic skills will matter**. Believe me you don't want to fly a Dread under-skilled.

**However, there are two sets of skills you absolutely need** if you don't want your BS to be a shiny brick drifting in space and waiting to be on your enemies' killmails:

- **You need to shoot**. Fit appropriate turrets ([Blasters](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Ion_Siege_Blaster_Cannon_I) or [railguns](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Dual_1000mm_Railgun_I) for a
  Moros) and a [Siege Module](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Siege_module_I) (This is not optional).
- **You need to move efficiently**. [Jump](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Jump_Drive_Operation) [drive](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Jump_Drive_Calibration) [skills](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Jump_Fuel_Conservation) !

Comment: I am playing Eve since 4 years, so I do have a general idea of the matter. I just wanted to make sure that I did not miss anything and also thought this might be a good question along with the other for the content of the site in general. Besides that, I am not gonna buy it tomorrow since I do not even have BS V as Industrialist. I just happen to like the Hull of the Moros and thats why I consider getting one for combat. Carrier is on the way, so maybe I buy one along the way.

Comment: I hope I did not offend you. I did not meant to judge your skills / experience. But as you pointed out, this question will remain on arQAde, and will be read by new EVE players who will be in for a big disappointment if they rush to Dreadnought :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample skill package for a Moros. The numbers are the recommended levels.

Engineering:

```
Energy Management 4
Energy Systems Operation 5
Engineering 5
```

Gunnery:

```
Advanced Weapon Upgrades 5
Capital Hybrid Turret 2
Controlled Bursts 4  
Large Hybrid Turret 5   
Gunnery 5
Medium Hybrid Turret 3
Motion Prediction 4 
Rapid Firing 4  
Sharpshooter 4   
Surgical Strike 3 
Tactical Weapon Reconfiguration 3 
Trajectory Analysis 3
Weapon Upgrades 5
```

Mechanics:

```
Capital Repair Systems 3  
EM Armor Compensation 3 
Explosive Armor Compensation 3
Hull Upgrades 5    
Kinetic Armor Compensation 3
Mechanics 5
Repair Systems 5  
Thermic Armor Compensation 3
```

Navigation:

```
Jump Drive Calibration 5
Jump Drive Operation 5 
Jump Fuel Conservation 4
Navigation 5
Warp Drive Operation 5
```

Science:

```
Biology 3
Cybernetics 2
Nanite Control 3 
Neurotoxin Recovery 3 
Science 5
Thermodynamics 3
```

Spaceship Command:

```
Advanced Spaceship Command 5
Gallente Battleship 5
Gallente Cruiser 4
Gallente Dreadnought 3
Gallente Frigate 4
Capital Ships 3
Spaceship Command 5
```